# Twitter working fine in emulator but not in device

Tags: exception, emulation, device

I am working with Android 1.6 and twitter4j.2.1.11

I am trying to connect twitter from my android mobile device . Thing is i am able to post the tweet from emulator,same application is not able to post through android mobile device.I am getting below exception , when i try to post thro mobile device.

oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Received authentication challenge is null

could any one pls help me in this regard.

Regards
Saran

Comment: I am trying to integration twitter in my app also, and getting same error!
I am searching forums since 2 days, and no useful answer
everybody is just saying check the phone's time, and nothing else, 
this is very riddiculous

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by changing sim card,
that was sim card not updating my time on network, I changed the sim card,
and set the date time to automatic update in my phone, and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem and was convinced it wasnt from my date and time until i checked properly and discovered that my auto update set the time to AM instead of PM . I changed it and the problem was solved